# Taskhost.exe looking suspicious in Process Explorer

Tags: windows, malware

I'm thinking I have a virus on my Windows 8 (x64). I downloaded and opened Process Explorer (Sysinternals) and started analyzing the running processes.

I came across taskhost.exe and saw it did not have a Description nor a Company Name. When I opened the details, it show the dialog below. This looks very suspicious, I thought.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 3]

So I searched for it and came across other people exploring taskhost.exe with process explorer. On the link below is someone showing taskhost with the dlls it is using. Mine show no dlls at all.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/244864/why_is_taskhost_consuming_so_much_of_my_cpu_.html

While I was typing this, I noticed an other taskhost.exe spawned.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Is this a virus? I ran AVG multiple times but it did not find the thing. I can't run it specifically on this file because it can't be found.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Why don't you just search for all locations of taskhost.exe but I can tell you that what your presenting isn't strnage in the slightlest.

Comment: I search for taskhost.exe, and the only on I found was in System32. That one I scanned, but it did not bring back something. @Ramhound, you meant _is strange_, I presume?

Comment: Are you running Process Explorer as administrator?  Have you checked the parent process to see if one of the services that it is running is the task scheduler service?

Comment: Mmmh, I guess I wasn't. Though I started it from WinRAR, which I do run as administrator. This solved the issue of not finding the path. Though it's still kind of strange that for the process taskhostex.exe (also System32), it display all the information correctly...

Comment: Just because the processes are similarly named, doesn't mean they will behave similarly. From the web:
"There are two types of services in Windows, Registry based services and DLL based services. Whenever your computer boots up, windows registers all of the required DLL’s and runs the services associated with them. Taskhost.exe is the process which controls all DLL based services."

Answer (score 0):

Relevant answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/448440/how-do-i-determine-what-taskhost-exe-is-doing

Summary: It's the Reliability Analysis Collection task.

Comment: For me, it was DiskFootprint->Diagnostics. Happy now that notebook fan is not blowing every few minutes..